# Why was my Canadian visit visa rejected due to deadline, despite deadline extension?

Tags: canada, visa-refusals

I had previously submitted a visitor visa application for my spouse and subsequently received a request for biometric submission.

During the time of this request, we were traveling and found it impossible to secure an appointment for biometrics in our location for several weeks. Consequently, we sought and obtained an extension from the authorities, granting us a few additional weeks to fulfill the requirement.

Despite this extension, I was surprised to receive a denial notice today, citing the following reason:

> Your application has been denied due to non-compliance with information requests, as outlined in subsection 16(1) of the IRPA. Specifically, you have not provided the requested biometric photographs and fingerprints.

This outcome is confusing, because the deadline to submit the biometrics, as per the extension granted, has not yet passed. Could anyone provide clarity on why the rejection was issued before the extended deadline?

Comment: Looks like a simple administrative mistake?  Appeal and explain that you were granted an extension.

Comment: Biometrics?! That's Orwellian, man. Screw traveling to Canada.

Comment: @Mentalist Unfortunately you'd find few and fewer places among developed countries to travel to, depending on your citizenship and consequent entitlement.

Answer (score 18):

> Could anyone provide clarity on why the rejection was issued before the extended deadline?

Like the comment said, it is likely just an administrative mistake, which unfortunately is quite common with IRCC nowadays.

You should contact IRCC using the [Webform](https://secure.cic.gc.ca/enquiries-renseignements/canada-case-cas-eng.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) to explain the issue (attach proof of extension and if possible your biometric appointment) to see if they can rescind the refusal.

This is mainly to avoid submitting a new application and declaring visa refusal in future applications to Canada or other countries. If they do not rescind the refusal, you must declare it in the future (but you almost always have an oppoturnity to explain the circumstances). Refusal for non-compliance with information request does not affect your future applications to Canada (as long as you provide the requested information in the future), but you must still declare it unless the refusal was rescinded.